Nomenclature "property of being ordered"
I would like to define a logic-like system / calculus in which some of the axioms and inference rules essentially express that the universe of discourse resembles a partial order.
In this context, I am looking for two (ideally single-word) nouns that would typically be used in a mathematical jargon:

The noun expressing the property that something can be ordered.
I only know the German term "Ordenbarkeit". chatGPT tells me, the English translation of Ordenbarkeit is orderability. Does not sound quite right to me. Orderableness also sounds weird.

The noun expressing the property that something is ordered.
chatGPT: orderliness. That does not sound right either.


I am aware of the well-ordering theorem / axiom of choice / etc. - this is not my point. I would like to give a proper name to a group of axioms.

Regarding 2, an ordered set. Regarding 1, everything can be ordered.

@LeeMosher Does that remain true even in the absence of Choice?  I know you need Choice to be assured a set can be well ordered.

@LeeMosher, ordered set does not really name the property that something is ordered but the ordered object itself, no?

@RobertShore I have no axiom of choice or anything alike in my system.

Reaching for standard single word terminologies is a stretch.  Instead, I suggest common sense. For example, your closing sentence can be addressed by the group of axioms known as the axioms of a linearly ordered set.

If a set possesses a binary operation that satisfies the axioms of a linearly ordered set, you can say that the set is linearly orderable. That's an adjective, not a noun. So, if you insist on a noun for the property referred to by that adjective then you could perphaps say linear orderability. In both cases feel free to drop the linear part of the terminology, and instead say orderable and orderability. But, as said, that last word is a stretch; I'm not aware of any better noun for that property.

Thanks @LeeMosher ! Any suggestion for 2?

As something of an order theorist and a [no modifiers here] native speaker of English, I’d say the best word for #2 would be orderedness. According to The Oxford English Dictionary, the word has been in use since at least 1724, though certainly not always with precisely this meaning.
